# Can "Password admin" change other admin's passwords?

Tags: passwords, admin, office365

My question is related to this site : https://support.office.com/en-SG/article/Assigning-admin-roles-eac4d046-1afd-4f1a-85fc-8219c79e1504

I want to know if the password admins can change the password of the others admin.
On the link above, the article say : "Password admin: Resets passwords, manages service requests, and monitors service health. Password admins are **limited to** resetting passwords for users and **other password admins**."

But, in the secion "View admin permissions by role", in the same site, I read : "Yes; with limitations. This admin can only reset passwords for non-admins."

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not Office 365 tech support.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a forum for computer programming, not administration.  A question of this nature should probably go on the Server Fault site.